# Client TLS handshake failed with x509 error: cert is valid for localhost, not remoteAddress

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to join my Hyperledger Fabric peer node to my channel that I created. I am using this AWS beginner guide, specifically Step 6 which is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/latest/hyperledger-fabric-dev/get-started-create-channel.html).

The error I'm receiving is below:

```
Client TLS handshake failed after 3.05693ms with error: x509: certificate is valid for ca.m-2lkym65za5e47ckxbi5eml6lba.n-ve2sxmaifrdadofkmiqyhyzpn4.managedblockchain.us-east-1.amazonaws.com, localhost, nd-kxfjssoerrefvhi7nwypvithgi.m-2lkym65za5e47ckxbi5eml6lba.n-ve2sxmaifrdadofkmiqyhyzpn4.managedblockchain.us-east-1.amazonaws.com, not ca.m-21kym65za5e47ckxbi5em161ba.n-ve2sxmaifrdadofkmiqyhyzpn4.managedblockchain.us-east-1.amazonaws.com remoteaddress=172.31.82.219:30002
Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to ca.m-21kym65za5e47ckxbi5em161ba.n-ve2sxmaifrdadofkmiqyhyzpn4.managedblockchain.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:30002: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
```

Below is the command I'm running to join the peer node to the channel.

```
docker exec cli peer channel join -b mychannel1.block -o orderer.n-ve2sxmaifrdadofkmiqyhyzpn4.managedblockchain.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:30001 --cafile /opt/home/managedblockchain-tls-chain.pem --tls
```

I've tried to use crs.hosts in the command to add remoteaddress to hosts but that didn't work. Can add more info if needed.